# Object doesn’t support this property or method - 'open'

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have upgraded my browser to IE9 and this problem has started. It works fine in IE8.

I want to open image in lightbox.

`<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="jQuery.prettyPhoto.open('filepath', 'test', 'test');" title="test">View image</a>`

but onclick of view image it shows error "Object doesn't support property or method 'open'".

Please anyone. help!!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: This might help. http://www.javascriptjunkie.com/?p=12#comment-181

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suggest something not loading on the face of it...

any chance you can switch to unobtrusive JS? attache the click event to the element with javascript and go from there - thats just a point on execution rather than a possible cause BTW